# How to read a CSV file but exclude certain columns containing blanks using Get-Content

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to read a CSV file and exclude rows where dynamically selected columns contain blanks but not all rows of those dynamically selected columns contain blanks.

Trying to use the where clause in the statement below (but not working):

```
Get-Content $Source -ReadCount 1000 |
  Where {
    ForEach($NotEqualBlankCol in $BlankColumns)
    {
      $NotEqualBlankCol -ne $null -and $NotEqualBlankCol -ne ''}
    } |
      ConvertFrom-Csv |
        Sort-Object -Property $SortByColNames.Replace('"', '') -Unique |
          .
          .
          .
            | Out-File $Destination
```

$BlankColumns is my dynamic object string array which I would like to loop through containing the column names of the CSV that are blank. it can be 1 column or more. When more then all of the selected columns need to be blank to qualify as a row that does not need to be included in the final CSV file output.

How do I do it using Get-Content? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine the coloums your are looking to check? So if any/all of those "columns" are blank? Import-CSV should do this just fine? Do you need Get-Content because of the csv size?

Comment: Sorry I reread the part about $BlankColumns

Comment: Matt. Thank you for replying. Yes and no to the size. Size varies but already using Get-Content in my tool in several areas to distinguish different situations via parameters. I know I can place it in a different method but trying to avoid multiple overwrites to the output file.

$BlankColumns is a parameter which it reads from my method.

Comment: Does your data have nested delimiters in strings? Can we assume there isnt?

Comment: For now no nested delimiters. I did think about it and it may complecate my method. Perhaps a future feature either within the current method or on a different method depending on how easy it will be.

Comment: Import-CSV removes most of that complication so you would not really have to worry about it.

Comment: Ok so there is no "simple" way to do this using Get-Content. A separate Import-CSV is needed. How would I do it to accomplish this dynamically? (not need to worry about sorting etc as my Get-Content already does the sorting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Get-Content

Ok. So what this will do it read in the contents of a file X lines at a time. It will parse each line into its indiviual columns. Then it will check the specified columns for blanks. If *any* of the flagged columns contains a black then it will be filtered out. Consider the test data I used for this

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address
1,Christina,Tucker,ctucker0@bbc.co.uk,Female,91.33.192.187
2,Jacqueline,Torres,jtorres1@shop-pro.jp,Female,205.70.183.107
3,Kathy,Perez,kperez2@hugedomains.com,Female,35.175.154.127
4,"",Holmes,eholmes3@canalblog.com,,
5,Ernest,Walker,ewalker4@marketwatch.com,Male,140.110.129.21
6,,Garza,cgarza5@jugem.jp,,
7,,Cunningham,jcunningham6@ox.ac.uk,Female,
8,,Clark,lclark7@posterous.com,,
9,,Ortiz,lortiz8@shareasale.com,,
```

Notice that the first_name and gender are blank for some of these folks. id 1,2,3,5,10 have complete data. The rest should be filtered.

```
$BlankColumns = "first_name","gender"
$headers = (Get-Content $path -TotalCount 1).Split(",")
$potentialBlankHeaderIndecies = 0..($headers.Count - 1) | Where-Object{$BlankColumns -contains $headers[$_]}
$potentialBlankHeaderIndecies 

Get-Content $path -ReadCount 3 | Foreach-Object{
    # Check to see if any of the indexes from a split are empty
    $_ | Where-Object{
        [bool[]](($_.Split(","))[$potentialBlankHeaderIndecies] | ForEach-Object{
            ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim('"'))
        }) -notcontains $false
    }
}
```

The output of this code is the file, as string, with the removed entries. You can just pipe this into a variable, file or what even you need.

To go into a little more detail we take the header names we want to check and this read in the first line of the csv file. That should contain the column names. Using that we determine the column indexes that we want to scrutinize. The we read in the whole file and parse it line by line. For each line we split on the comma and check the elements matching the identified headers. Check each of those elements if they are blank or null. We trim quotes in case it is a string "" which I will assume you would count as blank. Of all the elements we evaluate as a Boolean whether or not it is empty. If at least one is then it fails the `where-object` clause and gets ommited.

### Using Import-CSV

```
$BlankColumns = "first_name","gender"

Import-CSV $path | Where-Object{
    $line = $_
    ($BlankColumns | ForEach-Object{
        ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($line.$_.Trim('"')))
    }) -notcontains $false
}
```

Very similar approach just a lot less overhead since we are dealing with objects now instead of strings.

Now you could use `Export-CSV` or `ConvertFrom-CSV` depending on your needs in the rest of the project.

### Changing the filter criteria.

Both examples above filter columns where *any* of the columns contain blanks. If you want to omit only where *all* are blank change the line `}) -notcontains $false` to `}) -contains $true`

Comment: Thank you will work with your solution but will change to evaluate if all potential columns are blank.  If one potential column has data then the entire row must be included. In your example under my need if both  first_name and gender is blank do not return row.  If either (first_name is blank and genter not blank) or (first_name not blank and gender blank) the row must still be returned.

Comment: Ah ok.... That is pretty easy to account for then. Some minor changes should fix that.

Comment: @CostaZachariou Read my update on the bottom. That small change will get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you I saw. Been busy with some other stuff. Will apply your solutions to my environment now.